# Go faster than cell2mat

Tags: matlab, cell

I'm optimizing some code at the moment and can't figure out a way to go faster than MATLAB's `cell2mat`. For now, the multiple uses of `cell2mat` in my code **represent more than 15% of the processing time**.

I think it can go faster than that, because i know the structure of the cell arrays i'll pass to the function.

Basically, the cell array is `NxN`, where :

1. The top left `(N-1)x(N-1)` block contains, in each cell, a `6x6` double matrix
2. The bottom right `(N,N)` cell is a `MxM` double matrix.
3. The other cells have the right dimensions for concatenating, i.e. :

The cells `(1:(N-1),N)` are `6xM` double matrices, the cells `(N,1:(N-1))` are `Mx6` double matrices. (Image added for the sake of clarity, there `N=207` and `M=300`)

[image]

As the cells will always be filled with doubles AND always be of dimension 2, i'm already only using a small piece of the `cell2mat` code, i.e. :

```
 function m = myCell2Mat(c)

    rows = size(c,1);


        m = cell(rows,1);
        % Concatenate one dim first
        for n=1:rows
            m{n} = cat(2,c{n,:});% 73% of the time spent here
        end
        % Now concatenate the single column of cells into a matrix
        m = cat(1,m{:});% 25.2% of the time spent there


  end
```

This doens't change the time spent much as (like one could imagine), the most time is spent on these lines.

**My question is :** Does anyone have an idea about how to remove the loop there? I tried something along the lines of :

```
N=207;
M=300;
C=cell(N,N);
for ii=1:N-1
  for jj=1:N-1
C{ii,jj}=rand(6);
  end
end

for kk=1:(N-1)
C{N,kk}=rand(M,6);
C{kk,N}=rand(6,M);
end

C{end}=rand(M,M);

tmp1=cat(1,C{:,1:(end-1)});
LeftPart=reshape(tmp1,[],6*(size(C,2)-1));

RightPart=cat(1,C{:,end});

Res=[LeftPart RightPart];
```

But it doesn't show any improvment in time.. (And gives a false result as the `reshape` operates columnwise)

I've thought about using a recursive function aswell but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because most of the MATLAB build-in functions are MEX files and usually you cannot increase the performance by writing a new version of that function as an m-file.

Comment: Thing is i think that knowing the structure of the input i'm passing should give the possibility to write an optimized function for this given purpose

Comment: @NKN are you sure that `cell2mat` is a MEX file?

Comment: Almost sure! as you said, you have to find a way to use these functions in an optimized way.

Comment: @NKN do you think i have to take a look at how to build a MEX file? It is known that cell2mat is far from being fast

Comment: `cell2mat` is not a built-in at least in R2014a.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input please?

Comment: Actually as a matter of interest your code is very similar to that of `cell2mat` without the error checking. `cell2mat` is optimised for 2D cells, so I don't think you will get much of a speed up.

Comment: @IKavanagh Interesting! Can you let us know, how it is possible to see the code inside the MATLAB functions? As far as I know, they are protected.

Comment: for `cell2mat` just type `edit cell2mat` in the command window @NKN

Comment: @NKN Those implemented as `.m` files can be viewed with `edit cell2mat`. Those implemented as built-in (C) functions will say they are built-in and you won't be able to view their source.

Comment: @IKavanagh yes exactly, i didn't expect a speed up by just removing the error checking to be honest, that was just for clarity.

Comment: yes I see that. For non m-files it gives just a bunch of comments.

Comment: I've edited my post to provide a sample input

Comment: @IKavanagh I know that for 1D cells a call to `[C{:}]` is way faster than a call to `cell2mat(C)` (around 4x), was wondering if there was a workaround for 2D cells

Comment: Not that I know of. `cell2mat` runs in 0.03 seconds for me on your sample.

Comment: Quite the same for me. Although i'm calling it around 6000 times, making it a big processing time. If the definitive answer is that it's not improvable, i guess i'll have to rethink the entire structure of the code in order to just not call it ^^ Thanks for your time anyways @IKavanagh and NKN ! (Do you think i have to delete the post by the way?)

Comment: Or you could rethink your data structure. The inner `(N-1)x(N-1)` could be stored as a `4D-Matrix` matrix which is typically faster than a cell.

Comment: It actually really represents a 2D matrix, only transformed into cells for better readability (as the 6x6 blocks represent a physical entity). Will look at the 4D matrix possibility though

Comment: No you don't need to delete the question. It is (in my opinion) a good question (although improvement is possible). My final suggestion would be to seriously consider why you are storing the data in this way in the first place and if there is an alternative form you can use that doesn't use cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conclusion from the comments is, that there is no way to improve the performance of `cell2mat` significantly. Instead I would suggest a better data structure.

You wrote that the data actually represents a 2D-Matrix. Instead of splitting it up into blocks, it's faster to reshape it into a 4D matrix. Let's say your Cell is called `C` and `M` is the corresponding 2D matrix

```
%Old Code
q=C{1,1}
%Faster way to index the same
%1) Convert 2D matrix to 4D
blocksize=6
M=reshape(M,blocksize,size(M,1)/blocksize,blocksize,size(M,2)/blocksize);
%2) Index a block
q=squeeze(M(:,1,:,1))
```

As reshaping basically takes zero time, you could switch back to the 2D view, for example to process the last row / column. If you want to avoid the conversion back, it is possible to index multiple bocks at once. For the last column use: `reshape(M(:,206,:,207:end),6,[])` which corresponds to `C{206,207}`